# How to create a new Pandas dataframe from a filtered list?

Tags: python

I am wondering how can I create a new data frame based on an array of values.

Given an array of values:

`x1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']`

And given a data frame:

```
index, fruit, foo, bar
0, apple, true, false
1, pineapple, false, true
2, orange, true, true
3, banana, true, true
4, pear, true, true
```

How to create a new data frame which only contains the array x1 values?

Output data frame:

```
index, fruit, foo, bar
0, apple, true, false
1, orange, true, true
2, banana, true, true
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`pandas.Series.isin(values)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas-series-isin) which can be used to check if *elements in Series are contained in values.*

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...     {"fruit": ["apple", "pineapple", "orange"], "foo": ["true", "false", "true"]}
... )
>>>
>>> df
       fruit    foo
0      apple   true
1  pineapple  false
2     orange   true
>>> df[df.fruit.isin(['apple', 'orange', 'banana'])]
    fruit   foo
0   apple  true
2  orange  true
```